# How to add checkbox only in a particular row and column in a silver light grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, silverlight

I have a scenario in my project, where i have to generate check box only for 7th row second column.

Currently i have silver light grid control i am generating text column for all rows, but i need to genearate 7th row second column alone checkbox, can any one help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the good solution will be to add some bool property to the viewModel for example

```
public bool DisplayCheckbox { get; set;}
```

After that this text/checkbox column should be a TemplateColumn with TextBox and Checkbox. And it should be binded to this bool property sth like:

```
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Something">
        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding !DisplayCheckbox}"/>
                <CheckBox Visibility="{Binding DisplayCheckbox}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This bool property should switch TextBox/Checkbox.
Please consider this solution and remember that this code is only to show you the idea (it's not working I think). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot its working fine. Also can you please tell me how to validate grid cell values. For example if i dont want to allow other than number in a particular cell. I mean runtime check.

Comment: I'm glad that I could helped you. Speaking of validation I like to use IDataErrorInfo interface it's not very hard to implement and works & looks good. Example of article: http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-binding-and-idataerrorinfo.aspx If it's not enough for you please find some other articles but IDataErrorInfo is my choice.